# Change CSS class in head tag

Tags: jquery

Im adding a css class to head tag like:

```
$("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.classname{color: gold}</style>");
```

Now i need to change the color attribute i.e. from gold to green.
Any solutions for that?

Note: I NEED to do this in head tag. something like

```
$('.classname').css('color','green');
```

does not fit my requirements.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your style tag an identifier, like an ID, and you can reference it later and change it's content to whatever you like, if that's not possible you will have to figure out another way to select it, say based on it's content, index in the head etc. :

```
$("head").append("<style type='text/css' id='myStyle'>.classname {color: gold}</style>");​​

$("#myStyle").html('.classname {color: green}')
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ntrYr/)

**EDIT:**

Or you can insert a new style tag below the one you have to override a style :

```
$("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.classname {color: gold; font-weight: bold}</style>");

$("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.classname {color: green}</style>");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ntrYr/1/)

Or you can edit just the content and insert it again:

```
$("head").append("<style type='text/css' id='myStyle'>.classname {color: gold; font-weight: bold}</style>");

var css = $("#myStyle").text().replace('gold', 'green');
$("#myStyle").text(css);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ntrYr/2/)

Im my opinion changing the CSS with javascript by appending style tags to the head section is a really bad idea when javascript already has methods that are much better and more maintainable already built in with the `element.style` or jQuery's `css()` version.

Comment: quite nice, but this is more overwriting than editing, right?
real editing would be nessecary because there might be some more attributes in this class
for example adding, changing and deleting attributes

Comment: Well, yes, it's a tag like anything else and you can change it's content if you can reference it, and that's basically whay you are trying to do. You could also just insert a new style tag below the one you already have, but in many cases doing things this way ends up with unmaintainable code.